# SQL OPENXML Issue With Importing Data On The Same Node Level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nodes, openxml

I have a log file in XML format, for which I'd like to schedule an automated import into SQL. I'm able to partially import the data using OPENROWSET and OPENXML, however I'm unable to import some data as it's at the same node level. Specifically the 'user' node is on the same level as the 'storageObject' and the 'cabinet' node is on the same level as 'Client', 'Matter' etc.

Example XML:

```xml
<ActivityLog repositoryId="ZZ-T6KQ1I1B" repositoryName="Training" startDate="2017-07-01" endDate="2017-09-18">
    <activity date="2017-08-08T10:29:02" name="change access list" host="127.0.0.1">
        <user id="JS" name="John Smith" memberType="I" />
        <storageObject docId="4161-1264-9996" name="Hello World" size="0" fileExtension="eml">
            <cabinet name="Materials">QPIRVQK</cabinet>
        </storageObject>
    </activity>
    <activity date="2017-08-08T10:29:03" name="change access list" host="127.0.0.1">
        <user id="JS" name="John Smith" memberType="I" />
        <storageObject docId="4161-1264-9996" name="Screen Shot" size="0" fileExtension="jpg">
            <cabinet name="Materials">QPIRVQK</cabinet>
            <Client>1011</Client>
            <Matter>007</Matter>
            <Author>EMAIL</Author>
            <DocumentType>JPG</DocumentType>
        </storageObject>
    </activity>
</ActivityLog>
```

My T-SQL script:

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x=L
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Log.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Log(L)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, 'ActivityLog/activity/storageObject/cabinet', 1)
WITH (
        activitydate datetime '../../@date',
        activityname nvarchar(max) '../../@name',
        host nvarchar(32) '../../@host',
        id nvarchar(32) '../@id',
        username nvarchar(max) '../@username',
            memberType nvarchar(50) '../@memberType',
        docId nvarchar(50) '../@docId',
        filename nvarchar(max) '../@filename',
        size int '../@size',
        fileExtension nvarchar(max) '../@fileExtension',
        cabinetname nvarchar(max) '@cabinetname',
        Client nvarchar(max) '@Client',
        Matter nvarchar(max) '@Matter',
        Author nvarchar(max) '@Author',
        DocumentType nvarchar(max) '@DocumentType'
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

The above script returns everything except for the user tags: id, username(name), memberType and Client, Matter, Author and DocumentType. If anyone could offer advice on how to import all activity, that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not used to working with `OPENXML`, from what I hear that is the old-school way of retrieving things from an XML document. The way I'm doing this is with XML functions that are supported in SQL Server. Specifically, XML functions:

- [`nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type)

  > The result of the nodes() method is a rowset that contains logical copies of the original XML instances. In these logical copies, the context node of every row instance is set to one of the nodes identified with the query expression, so that subsequent queries can navigate relative to these context nodes.
- [`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type)

  > Performs an XQuery against the XML and returns a value of SQL type

You'll see that for e.g. `id` (`<user>` attribute Id) you were on the wrong level, you had to go one deeper. For e.g. `<Client>` you were on the wrong level again, you have to go back one level to go up again. I did not find the filename attribute in your XML.

---

```
DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x=N'<ActivityLog repositoryId="ZZ-T6KQ1I1B" repositoryName="Training" startDate="2017-07-01" endDate="2017-09-18">
    <activity date="2017-08-08T10:29:02" name="change access list" host="127.0.0.1">
        <user id="JS" name="John Smith" memberType="I" />
        <storageObject docId="4161-1264-9996" name="Hello World" size="0" fileExtension="eml">
            <cabinet name="Materials">QPIRVQK</cabinet>
        </storageObject>
    </activity>
    <activity date="2017-08-08T10:29:03" name="change access list" host="127.0.0.1">
        <user id="JS" name="John Smith" memberType="I" />
        <storageObject docId="4161-1264-9996" name="Screen Shot" size="0" fileExtension="jpg">
            <cabinet name="Materials">QPIRVQK</cabinet>
            <Client>1011</Client>
            <Matter>007</Matter>
            <Author>EMAIL</Author>
            <DocumentType>JPG</DocumentType>
        </storageObject>
    </activity>
</ActivityLog>';
```

```
SELECT
    activitydate=n.v.value('../../@date','DATETIME'),
    activityname=n.v.value('../../@name','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    host=n.v.value('../../@name','NVARCHAR(32)'),
    id=n.v.value('../../user[1]/@id','NVARCHAR(32)'),
    username=n.v.value('../../user[1]/@name','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    memberType=n.v.value('../../user[1]/@memberType','NVARCHAR(50)'),
    docId=n.v.value('../@docId','NVARCHAR(50)'),
    filename=n.v.value('../@filename','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    size=n.v.value('../@size','INT'),
    fileExtension=n.v.value('../@fileExtension','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    cabinetname=n.v.value('@cabinetname','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    Client=n.v.value('../Client[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    Matter=n.v.value('../Matter[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    Author=n.v.value('../Author[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    DocumentType=n.v.value('../DocumentType[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM
    @x.nodes('ActivityLog/activity/storageObject/cabinet') AS n(v);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and the import process is fully automated now. Thank you, TT!